# How can we conclude that $\{ x: \phi(x) \}$ is a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking at the following **Theorem**:

Let $\phi$ a type. We suppose that there is a set $Y$, such that $\forall x(\phi(x) \to x \in Y)$. Then, there is the set $\{ x: \phi(x) \}$.

and I try to understand its proof.

From the axiom shema of specification, there is the set $V=\{ x \in Y: \phi(x) \}$

$$x \in V \leftrightarrow (x \in Y \wedge \phi(x))$$

How can we continue, in order to show that $\{ x: \phi(x) \}$ is a set?

Comment: Does your axiomatic system include the axiom schema of comprehension (unrestricted)?

Comment: No, we haven't done this...

Comment: It shouldn't, since this leads to problems.  For example $ \phi(x) \text { iff } x \text{ is a set} $. The axiom of specification actually states : $ \forall A, \exists B, \forall x (x \in B \text { iff } [ x \in A \land \phi (x) ] ) $.

Comment: I guess what I should have said in my above comment is that the axiom of specification only enables one to create sets with reference to other sets - i.e., to specify a subset.

Answer (score 1):

You want that

$$\{x|\phi(x)\}=\{x\in Y|\phi(x)\}$$
And this follows directly from your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The idea, here, is to show that $V$ contains and is contained in the alleged set. One inclusion is clear, since $V$ is the intersection of the alleged set with $Y.$ For the reverse inclusion, use what you know about the type $\phi$ and the set $Y.$

**Added**: On the one hand, suppose that $x\in V.$ That is, we have $x\in Y$ and $\phi(x).$ So, in particular, $\phi(x),$ meaning $x$ is a member of the alleged set. Since this holds for all $x\in V,$ then it follows that $V$ is contained in the alleged set.

On the other hand, suppose that $x$ is a member of the alleged set, meaning $\phi(x).$ Since $\phi(x),$ then by assumption, we know that $x\in Y.$ Hence, since $x\in Y$ and $\phi(x),$ then $x\in V$ by definition. Hence, $V$ contains the alleged set, as well.

By double-inclusion, $$V=\{x:\phi(x)\},$$ so the alleged set is, indeed, a set.

---

Hopefully, you see why that bit about $Y$ is essential to the proof. If we have no such condition, then we may not have a set at all. For example, suppose that $\phi(x)$ is the statement "$x=x.$" Then if $\{x:\phi(x)\}$ ***were*** a set, it would be the "set of all sets," which leads to a number of paradoxes, and so cannot exist.

Comment: Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: Well, for the reverse inclusion, start with an arbitrary element of the alleged set, say $x.$ By definition, we know that $\phi(x).$ What can we then conclude about $x$?

Comment: Cameron Buie In my notes, there is the following proof:
$$$$
From the axiom shema of specification, there is the set $Z=\{ x \in Y: \phi(x) \}$

$$x \in Z \leftrightarrow (x \in Y \wedge \phi(x)) \leftrightarrow \phi(x)$$

Therefore, $Z=\{x: \phi(x) \}$ and so $\{x: \phi(x) \}$ is a set.

Why does this stand?

$$x \in Z \leftrightarrow (x \in Y \wedge \phi(x)) \leftrightarrow \phi(x)$$

Because of the fact that for each $x$ that satisfies $\phi(x)$, we have that $x \in Y$ ?

Comment: Exactly! The first equivalence is simply by definition of $Z;$ the latter equivalence is half-obvious, and the other half follows from the relationship between $\phi$ and $Y,$ as you say. I will expand my answer to demonstrate further.

Answer (score 0):

$\{x:\phi(x)\}=V$, and you have proved that $V$ is a set.

Comment: $V$ is the set that contains all the elements $x$, that belong to $Y$ and satisfy the type $\phi$. But, we want to create a set, that contains all the elements that satisfy $\phi$, whether they belong to $Y$ or not. Or am I wrong?